# The pipeline is not Working Correctly in Windows

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am working on a little groovy script that will be execute a simple maven command.

I have the following groovy script.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git 'https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat 'mvn clean verify -Dprofile=int-s C:/Users/user/.m2/settings.xml -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/project/conf/cacerts'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing this on Windows so I don'w know why is note execute correctly the maven command.

Comment: Could you provide us with more details, please? I.E. any errors you get or expected output vs actual output

Comment: A space should insert before `-s` in `-Dprofile=int-s C:/Users/user/.m2/settings.xml`